# Telnet disable Job Control over telnet

Tags: ssh, ksh, telnet, putty

When logging to remote ksh using telnet (either putty or NET::Telnet) the Job Control is disabled.
using ssh with the same user it works.

Why? and how can I fix it?
Please. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telnet will never allow job control. It is a stand-alone client program but it is not a shell.

When you use ssh, you are ultimately invoking a shell and a feature of the shell is job control.

Also I agree with dgq7 that telnet is completely insecure.

Sorry.

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a secret hint that telnet should not be used anymore for it is considered unsecure due to generally not being encrypted.

Comment: Sometimes security is not something to consider, but development time is.

... NET::SSH::PERL is a problem to install on windows.